# Cannot open file in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I use Selenium IDE in Firefox to test my company's online software.

However, recently I am unable to open a file. I click the 'File' tab at the top, then click 'Open' from the menu. The menu closes but nothing happens. The 'Select File' window does not open. This only started happening in the last week.

Thanks.

Comment: While Selenium IDE may be a programming tool, this isn't really a programming question. I would look to the support site for Selenium IDE. Try rebooting, reinstalling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Install firefox version 53.0 and you should be able to open the file again.   The latest version of Firefox version 55 doesn't work.

Once you install the older version of firefox, go into options>advanced and turn off updates otherwise it will install 55 again.